# Compile Error: Function Call on Left-hand side of assignment

Tags: excel, vba

I got the compile error

> "Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object"

Trying to fix an inherited Excel file that calculates various values related to HVAC. The file relies on a couple of Add-In .xla files which contain many functions. I am unable to get results from most of the functions. Either I get numbers that immediately turn to zeros, or I just get #VALUE and #NAME errors.

My VBA skills are somewhat limited as well as my knowledge of the calculations this file is performing.

```
Function EvapDeltaGrn(altitude, evap_on, tdb_ma, hr_ma, sat_goal, hr_min)
    'use to calculate the delta grain when tdb_oa > than sat_goal

    EvapDeltaGrn = 0

    If tdb_ma = "" Then Exit Function
    If hr_ma = "" Then Exit Function

    If evap_on Then
        If tdb_ma >= (sat_goal) Then 'use evaporative cooling
            Enthalpy = Application.Run("'psychrometric functions.xla'!TdbGrainstoEnthalpy", altitude, tdb_ma, hr_ma)
            'Range("v14") = enthalpy
            EvapDeltaGrn = Application.Run("'psychrometric functions.xla'!TdbEnthalpytoGrains", altitude, sat_goal, Enthalpy)
            EvapDeltaGrn = EvapDeltaGrn - hr_ma
            EvapDeltaGrn = Round(EvapDeltaGrn, 2)
        Else    'evaporative humidification
            If hr_ma < hr_min Then EvapDeltaGrn = Round(hr_min - hr_ma, 2)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The error seems to be at `Enthalpy =`.

Comment: Do you have another function named `Enthalpy`?

Comment: And today I learned how to return a value with `Application.Run` @sadele89 Thanks!

Comment: Always declare your variables and always add `Option Explicit` on the very top of your code to prevent you from not doing so. What data type does the `'psychrometric functions.xla'!TdbGrainstoEnthalpy` return? What data type should `Enthalpy` be? Same goes for all the other variables as well.